# advanced page editor not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help i got big trouble in this :( in my wordpress theme i didn't edit advanced page editor when i did  `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

and then i get this error message i didn't know how to do this.

These errors i got :

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'allowed-shortcodes' in
>   config-templatebuilder/avia-template-builder/php/shortcode-template.class.php
>   on line 484

But in local this wordpress load good.

Please help me for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Amazon affiliates plugin enabled? If so, disable that and see if the error persists.

If the error is still there, is it still there then try a different theme as your current theme may not be compatible with the latest version of Wordpress.